# Site not indexed by Google

Tags: google, dns, search-engine-indexing

I typed the following on Google: (1) site: uniquevolve.com (2) site: uniquevolve.com.au

Only (2) gets indexed. Is this normal?

The strange thing is, my Website is actually hosted on the server with domain (1) and domain (2) only redirects to (1).

How do I get (1) indexed by Google?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it isn't redirecting for me.  Going to uniqueevolve.com.au keeps me at the .au domain for sure.  The right way to redirect this for Google to catch on is to do a 301 redirect (I would do it through .htaccess, but it's your call).

You can then setup an account with Google Webmaster Tools and let them know you've moved to the new domain as well.

Comment: Hi, the site is uniquevolve.com/uniquevolve.com.au. It only has one E in the middle.

Comment: Right, it was just a typo on my end, but I did visit both domains, and there still doesn't seem to be a functioning redirect in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect doesn't seem to be working. I can reach the same content under both domains.

Answer (score 0):

1) Choose which domain you want to be indexed and do a [301 redirect](http://www.isitebuild.com/301-redirect.htm) to it. If you are running Apache you can do this in an .htaccess file in your root web directory. It would look something like this (assuming uniquevolve.com is the primary domain):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?uniquevolve\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.uniquevolve.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will solve your duplicate content issues and will be good usability for your users (only one domain to keep track of)

2) Use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html). This may be considered redundant with #1 but you could always use this instead of #1 if you so chose to (although #1 is the better way to go). This tells the search engines which URL is the primary URL and to index that one, not any of the duplicates.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the redirection provided by my Web hosting provider instead of programatically doing it.

Comment: Their service seems either limited or flawed. I'd recommend doing yourself so you have full control over it. Plus if you ever change hosts this will keep working with no additional work on your part.